# multiple symbols in ggplot and legend

Tags: ggplot2, legend

I am plotting the number of animals at a given location in ggplot with R.  I would like to have locations with 0 animals be a different symbol and color than the graduate bubbles indicating how many animals were at a given location.  I would also like to have one legend with 0 and the symbol along with the other number of animal symbols.

Right now my plot looks like this:[image]

I can get the 0 locations with the correct formatting, but the legend is not correct.  All of the examples I have looked at are for categorical variables in legends.  Both legends are being written over each other.

Here is a sample data set:

```
    data<-  structure(list(StationID = c(201905001, 201905002, 201905003, 
201905004, 201905005, 201905006, 201905007, 201905008, 201905009, 
201905010, 201905011, 201905012, 201905013, 201905014, 201905015, 
201905016, 201905017, 201905018, 201905019, 201905020, 201905021, 
201905022, 201905023, 201905024, 201905025, 201905026, 201905027, 
201905028, 201905029, 201905030, 201905031, 201905032, 201905034, 
201905035, 201905036, 201905037, 201905038, 201905039, 201905040, 
201905041, 201905042, 201905044, 201905045, 201905046, 201905048, 
201905049, 201905050, 201905051, 201905052, 201905054), Gear = c("SURVEY", 
"SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", 
"SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", 
"SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", 
"SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", 
"SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", 
"SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", 
"SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY"
), Lat = c(36.6645350138346, 37.0178499996662, 37.033953332901, 
37.081911667188, 37.0729350010554, 37.1705300013224, 37.2492666721344, 
37.2472933292389, 37.2903200149536, 37.3738666534424, 37.4438433329264, 
37.492774995168, 37.518520005544, 37.5595200220744, 37.6054300308228, 
37.6420283635457, 37.6984833399455, 37.6936166763306, 37.679563331604, 
37.6498633066813, 37.6428966522217, 37.6056783040365, 37.6634216944377, 
37.685969988505, 37.7676633199056, 37.7726500193278, 37.8299016952515, 
37.9183833440145, 37.8489066441854, 37.8733599980672, 37.8649816513062, 
37.9110066731771, 37.990051651001, 37.9865533192952, 37.9665983200073, 
37.9797266642253, 38.0102166662614, 38.1030866702398, 38.0945499976476, 
38.1273333311081, 38.1618366718292, 38.1923666636149, 38.1334300041199, 
38.2355533281962, 38.2410600026449, 38.2800333340963, 38.3421416600545, 
38.3698199907939, 38.3274916648865, 38.3525416692098), Long = c(-74.7500300089518, 
-74.7316516876221, -74.900251642863, -74.8841716766357, -74.7262933095296, 
-74.5957000096639, -74.6847749710083, -74.7541166941325, -74.7457099914551, 
-74.7168299992879, -74.5491633097331, -74.6628299713135, -74.7597883224487, 
-74.713990020752, -74.8127300262451, -74.7373699824015, -74.6189666748047, 
-74.5948733647664, -74.5515900293986, -74.5577583312988, -74.4630050023397, 
-74.3338683446248, -74.4051549911499, -74.3499650001526, -74.4768716812134, 
-74.5951800028483, -74.7884666442871, -74.6335650126139, -74.5258650143941, 
-74.4273633321126, -74.2590316613515, -74.3657600084941, -74.2522833347321, 
-74.2789483388265, -74.5465349833171, -74.6023300170898, -74.6561850229899, 
-74.749963315328, -74.4301616668701, -74.393483320872, -74.3457133293152, 
-74.2502950032552, -74.077884999911, -74.0272833327452, -73.9452916463216, 
-73.9529799779256, -74.0033083334565, -74.1259333372116, -74.259871673584, 
-74.3140449841817), Sizeclass = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Greater_75", 
"Prerecruits", "Recruits"), class = "factor"), number = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35, 
0, 14.25, 1, 0, 4.25, 1.2, 0), density = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0241051468866054, 
0, 0.0112058148848937, 0.000612257270241685, 0, 0.00292258473097911, 
0.000731456735020721, 0)), row.names = c(5L, 11L, 18L, 22L, 29L, 
36L, 42L, 48L, 54L, 60L, 65L, 70L, 76L, 84L, 89L, 96L, 101L, 
107L, 114L, 118L, 126L, 131L, 137L, 143L, 150L, 154L, 160L, 166L, 
172L, 179L, 186L, 192L, 198L, 202L, 208L, 214L, 220L, 226L, 233L, 
238L, 244L, 251L, 257L, 262L, 270L, 275L, 282L, 288L, 294L, 299L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Example code for plot.  I exclude lines with shapefiles from the ggplot code and example data set is only the first 50 rows of my real dataset so example data plot will not look like the plot below I'm working on:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = data[data$Sizeclass=="Prerecruits" & data$number>0,], aes(x = Long, y = Lat, size = number),col="red") +
  geom_point(data = data[data$Sizeclass=="Prerecruits" & data$number==0,], aes(x = Long, y = Lat, size = number),col="black",shape=3) +
  xlim(-76,-71)+
  ylim(36,42)+
  ggtitle("MAB Survey Pre Recruits (< 35mm)") +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude",size="Number per Tow") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.title=element_text(size=14),
        text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", size = 12),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black", size = 12),
        legend.position=c(0.8, 0.2),
        legend.justification=c(.5,.5), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but you could try making a category based on less than zero/greater than zero and then map that category to the shape/color:

```
data %>%
  mutate(shape = ifelse(number > 0, "greater", "zero")) %>%
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = Long, y = Lat, size = number, shape=shape, color=shape)) +
  xlim(-76,-71)+
  ylim(36,42)+
  ggtitle("MAB Survey Pre Recruits (< 35mm)") +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude",size="Number per Tow") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.title=element_text(size=14),
        text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", size = 12),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black", size = 12),
        legend.position=c(0.8, 0.2),
        legend.justification=c(.5,.5), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = NA))
```

That got me this. You can always hide the legends if you don't like them, too.

[image]